# Botão "Adicionar" para tags favoritas cortado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design, layout

Não me recordo desse bug no beta, então imagino que seja relacionado à graduação. O botão **Adiconar** que aparece quando se clica em *editar* as tags favoritas, na coluna à direita do site, fica cortado:

No Chrome é pior:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas também acontece no Firefox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No IE também fica cortado (não vou postar ss, o IE não merece!)

A causa é bem simples: Nos sites em inglês, o texto é **Add**, que é bem menor. Para resolver, diminuir a caixa de texto pode fazer com que o espaço fique muito pequeno, então aproveito para deixar uma sugestão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Detalhe: Editei o CSS para o `+` ficar em um tamanho mais adequado, pois o padrão me pareceu muito pequeno. Isso pode ser um problema se a solução for apenas mudar a tradução.

Comment: No Chrome no meu tablet está OK. Não sei como está no PC, mas acredito em você.

Comment: Provável string a ser substituída na tradução: https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/40270777?q=Add

Comment: @bfavaretto Acabei não mencionando na pergunta, mas na minha imagem eu editei o CSS para o + ficar em um tamanho mais apropriado. Só alterar a tradução pode resolver a quebra mas deixar o botão estranho. Vou editar a pergunta com esse detalhe.

Comment: Eu sei, cheguei a simular como ficaria trocando o texto do botão no inspetor do Chrome. É que se for só trocar a string, é mais fácil (eu posso trocar, e o Gabe aprova se concordar). Se for pra alterar também o CSS, depende dos desenvolvedores do site (e talvez precise ser uma mudança válida em todos os sites da rede).

Comment: Gostei do `[  +  ]`. Podia deixar a palavra "adicionar" no atributo `title`, aparecendo somente quando o usuário estiver com o ponteiro do mouse sobre o botão. Que tal?